# Sending zip files using python(creating a dedicated server and client) for a clone of popular platforms like steam using socket in python

Tags: python, sockets

`enter code here`I don`t know why but client server are justing not intreseted in their messages for themselves and later on i see that my pc blocades the connection do you know how to fix it. It shows me winerror and I even looked for it inside the windows defender or firewalls ect. I hope that there is a quick solution for this problem.

client code:

```
import socket
import tqdm
import os
import time

SERVER_HOST = socket.gethostname()
SERVER_PORT = 5000

BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
SEPARATOR = "<SEPARATOR>"
gamename = "gra" 

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
print("Succesfully connected to the server")
s.send(gamename.encode("utf-8"))
print("data about downloaded game sended")
received = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode("utf-8")
print(received)
try:
    filename, filesize = received.split(SEPARATOR)
except:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
filename = "effect.zip"
filename = os.path.basename(filename)
print(filename)
filesize = int(filesize)
progress = tqdm.tqdm(range(filesize), f"Receiving {filename}", unit="B", 
unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024)
with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    while True:
        bytes_read = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not bytes_read:    
        break
    f.write(bytes_read)
         progress.update(len(bytes_read))
f.close()
```

server code here:

```
import socket
import tqdm
import os
import threading
import time

SEPARATOR = "<SEPARATOR>"
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096 

def send_file(host, port, buffer):
    while True:
        s = socket.socket()
        print("Starting")
        s.bind((host, port))
        s.listen(5)
        print("Started port "+str(port))
        client_socket, address = s.accept()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        received = client_socket.recv(buffer).decode("utf-8")
        filename = received + ".zip"
        print("received info about installation")
        filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
        print(f"{filename}{SEPARATOR}{filesize}")
        client_socket.send(f"{filename}{SEPARATOR}{filesize}".encode("utf-8"))
        progress = tqdm.tqdm(range(filesize), f"Sending {filename}", unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024)
        with open(filename, "rb") as f:
            while True:
                bytes_read = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
                if not bytes_read:
                    break
            client_socket.sendall(bytes_read)
            progress.update(len(bytes_read))
    s.close()
host = socket.gethostname()
send_file(host, 5000, BUFFER_SIZE)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please consider including the actual code and whatever messages get printed out.  As is, it's difficult to help you without the necessary information.

Comment: with this description you can get only one solution - hire programmer. We can't see your code, we can't run it and we can't read in your mind - so it would need magic help you. You have to put all details in question (not in comment)

Comment: I test code and you main mistake are indentations. In server you should have `send_all` and `progress.update()` inside `while True` but you have it outside. In client you have the same problem in `while True` (PL: główny problem to wcięcie kodu - część kodu powinna być wewnątrz `while True` ale jest na zewnątrz - za `while True` - więc to powodouje, że `while` jest wykonywane w nieskończoność)

Comment: second problem is `socket`. It is pomitive object and it may not know if it get all data - and `if not bytes_read: break` may not work. Partial solution is `if len(bytes_read) < BUFFER_SIZE: break` but sometimes you may have data with size `BUFFER_SIZE * N` and this wil not work. Safe is to use some protocol for sending data - or to create own protocol (rules). Server could convert `filesize` to 4 bytes (`struct.pack("I", filesize)`) and send it to client before data. And then client has to get 4 bytes, convert to integer `struct.unpack("I", size)` and use it to control if it get all data.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in this code

**First:**

You have wrong indentations and some lines are outside `while True` but they should be inside.

**client.py**

```
with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    while True:
        bytes_read = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

        # the lines below should to be inside `while True`

        if not bytes_read:    
            break

        f.write(bytes_read)
        progress.update(len(bytes_read))
```

**server.py**

```
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            bytes_read = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            if not bytes_read:
                break

            # the lines below should to be inside `while True`

            client_socket.sendall(bytes_read)
            progress.update(len(bytes_read))
```

Wrong indentations in `client.py` makes it never end `while`-loop.

Second:

`Socket` is pimitive object and may not inform client when there is end of data - and code `if not bytes_read: break` may not work. Or it may temporary problems
with connection and gives `bytes_read = 0` which may close connection before server sends all data.

You should use `filesize` to check if you get all data. You can count down it - substract size of received bytes from `filesize` untill you get `0`

**client.py**

```
with open(filename, "wb") as f:

    while filesize > 0:   # <--- use `filesize`

        bytes_read = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

        # this may not work
        if not bytes_read:   
            break

        filesize -= len(bytes_read)   # <--- use `filesize` 
        
        f.write(bytes_read)
        progress.update(len(bytes_read))

# --- after loop ---

if filesize == 0:
    print('download completed')
else:                
    print('download uncomplete, missing', filesize, 'bytes')
```

---

I see other possible problem.

Client sends `gamename` to server and server sends `f"{filename}{SEPARATOR}{filesize}"` to client. Socket may sends data slited in smaller parts and send them with delay so in both situation it may send it partially and then server may get incomplete `gamename` and tries to use wrong file name. The same can happend with `f"{filename}{SEPARATOR}{filesize}"` - client may get only part of this and later it can get rest when it will get file data and will save it in file - so you create incorrect file.

You should send one byte with size of sended data and other side should first read one byte with this size and use it to read correct from server.

Example for `f"{filename}{SEPARATOR}{filesize}"`

**server.py** - send information

```
# - send header -

# convert info to header

header = f"{filename}{SEPARATOR}{filesize}"
header_bytes = header.encode("utf-8")
header_size = len(header_bytes)

print('header:', header)

# first send 1-byte with header size

size = struct.pack("B", header_size)
client_socket.sendall(size)

# next send header

client_socket.sendall(header_bytes)
```

**client.py** - recv information

```
# - recv header -
                
# first recv 1-byte with header size

size = s.recv(1)
header_size = struct.unpack("B", size)[0]

# next recv header

header_bytes = s.recv(header_size)
header = header_bytes.decode('utf-8')
print('header:', header)

# convert header to info

filename, filesize = header.split(SEPARATOR)
filesize = int(filesize)
```

---

Full code with other changes

**server.py**

```
import socket
import tqdm
import os
import time
import struct

# --- constants ---

SEPARATOR = "<SEPARATOR>"
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096

# --- functions ---

def send_file(host, port, buffer_size):

    print(f"Starting {host}:{port}")

    s = None   # default value at start
    
    try:

        s = socket.socket()   # standard options TCP/IP

        # solution for "[Error 89] Address already in use". Use before bind()
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

        s.bind((host, port))

        # kolejka klientów oczekujących na połączenie (max 5 klientów)
        s.listen(5)

        # --- loop ---

        while True:

            print("\nWaiting for client")

            client_socket, client_address = s.accept()
            print("Client:", client_address)

            try:
                time.sleep(0.5)

                # --- recv request ---
                
                received = client_socket.recv(buffer_size).decode("utf-8")
                filename = received + ".zip"

                print("received info about installation")
                filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)

                # --- send response ---
                
                # - send header -

                # convert info to header
                header = f"{filename}{SEPARATOR}{filesize}"
                header_bytes = header.encode("utf-8")
                header_size = len(header_bytes)
                
                print('header:', header)

                # first send 1-byte with header size
                size = struct.pack("B", header_size)
                client_socket.sendall(size)

                # next send header
                client_socket.sendall(header_bytes)

                # - send data -

                progress = tqdm.tqdm(range(filesize), f"Sending {filename}", unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024)

                # send file
                with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                    while True:
                        bytes_read = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
                        if not bytes_read:
                            break

                        client_socket.sendall(bytes_read)
                        progress.update(len(bytes_read))

                        # simulate slow connection (and see progress bar)
                        time.sleep(0.5)

                progress.close()  # stop displaying forgotten updates of progress bar
                
                print('[DEBUG] end of file')
                
            except BrokenPipeError as ex:
                print('[Exception]', ex)
                
            # --- after loop ---
            
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Stopped by Ctrl+C')
    finally:    
        print('Closing')    
        if s is not None:
            s.close()

# --- main ---

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = socket.gethostname()
    send_file(host, 5000, BUFFER_SIZE)
```

**client.py**

```
import socket
import tqdm
import os
import time
import struct

# --- constants ---

SEPARATOR = "<SEPARATOR>"
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096

# --- other ---

SERVER_HOST = socket.gethostname()
SERVER_PORT = 5000

gamename = "gra" 

# ---------------------------------------

s = socket.socket()

# --- connect ---

s.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
print("Succesfully connected to the server", (SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))

# --- send request ---

request = gamename
request_bytes = request.encode("utf-8")
s.sendall(request_bytes)
print("request about downloaded game sended")

# --- recv response ---
                
# - recv header -
                
# first recv 1-byte with header size
size = s.recv(1)
header_size = struct.unpack("B", size)[0]

# next recv header
header_bytes = s.recv(header_size)
header = header_bytes.decode('utf-8')
print('header:', header)

# convert header to info
filename, filesize = header.split(SEPARATOR)
filesize = int(filesize)

# - recv data -

progress = tqdm.tqdm(range(filesize), f"Receiving {filename}", unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024)

# change name only for tests
filename = 'output.zip'

with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    while filesize > 0:
        bytes_read = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

        if not bytes_read:   
            break

        filesize -= len(bytes_read)
        
        f.write(bytes_read)
        progress.update(len(bytes_read))
        
        # simulate slow connection (and see progress bar)
        time.sleep(0.5)

progress.close()  # stop displaying forgotten updates of progress bar
                
if filesize == 0:
    print('download completed')
else:                
    print('download uncomplete, missing', filesize, 'bytes')

# --- close ---
    
f.close()
```